# Is this a DNS or server-side error?

Tags: dns, http-code-500

I am having difficulty accessing a specific website. (I get 500 Server fault errors) 
I can access this site on my iPhone when NOT connected to WiFi. 
I CANNOT access the site when connected to WiFi or via a Ethernet connection to my home network.

I thought it might be a DNS issue, so I copied the DNSservers from a friend who has a different ISP, and has no problem access the site. No luck. Also tried some of the public DNS servers out there, again, with no luck.

Does anyone have any idea on how to trace this issue?

Comment: can you post your .htaccess file? have you tried to access the site from a completely different place, like your house or a friends house?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about another website, not under your control.

Comment: Try changing your home IP.

Comment: Wow. I just saw a comment from Aug 20 ^ and I wanted to reply to it that there's no point to do that. Until I noticed it was my own...

Answer (score 1):

a 500 error means a problem with the server, which most of the time, is caused by wrong rules on the .htaccess file.

Assuming that your site is hosted in a hosting company and considering that you can access the site using a data connection, but not wifi, basically means that one of the IPs is being blocked. The external IP from the router.

It may also mean that you have a rule that redirects the request and an infinite loop has occurred, so the server cuts the process and sends the 500.

Comment: I understand about the 500 errors, however, the site in question is not mine. The site seems to work fine, conditionally. 

As long as I am on my local network, I cannot access it. however, my friend (on a seperate network, in another state) CAN access it, and I can access it when my phone is using the Cell data, NOT wifi.

Comment: I assume you mention the "works fine" to answer the aspect of infinite redirects, that still may happen if a rule is being executed depending on IP. If you can access the site using data plan, but not your local network, which I assume has Internet access, the problem seems to be IP related, as I mentioned before. 500 errors occur because the server is in a state of confusion and can't serve the resource, so if it an serve it to other clients, but not your client (requesting IP), then your client is the problem for the server.

Comment: contact the owner of the site, and ask about any block to your IP. Also, if you know anybody else with an IP similar to yours, try to access the site from that place/computer